# Currency History Tracking

Tags: multi-currency, currency

I am building a custom visual force page and one of the bottle necks is the lack of a "History" related list.

I am building the "History" component first but I hit a roadblock: Tracking CurrencyIsoCode. I see that Salesforce is able to track currency changes even when Currency history tracking is disabled. Is there another source of currency information that I am not able to see?

I can probably enable it and track it for future records but its going to be a problem for legacy records for which the currency code was not tracked.

Comment: You mean [`DatedConversionRate`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_datedconversionrate.htm)? It doesn't mention `create()` permission so I wouldn't have high hopes... Maybe contact support. I saw that FinancialForce app guys keep their own currency objects.